# An interesting property of characteristic function

Tags: probability, characteristic-functions

I find the following interesting fact when I study the characteristic functions in probability theory.

For any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, the following inequality holds

$$
\min_{t\in [1,5]}|1-e^{itx}|\le 1.
$$

Proof: if $|x|\le \frac{\pi}{3}$, take $t=1$, the inequality holds; if $|x|>\frac{\pi}{3}$, then the range of the argument of $e^{itx}$ (which is $4|x|>\frac{4\pi}{3}$) will intersect with $[-\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi}{3}]$ on the circle, the conclusion also holds.

I'm curious that whether the following generalized version is true:

$$
\min_{t\in [1,5]} |1-\psi(t)|<1,
$$

where $\psi(t)=\mathbb{E}_{p}[e^{itx}]$ is any characteristic function of probability measure $p$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I would start by testing a measure concentrated on two points. Have you tried that ?

Comment: By a result of Polya, $\phi(t)=\max(1-|t|,0)$ is a characteristic function, so $\min_{t\in[1,5]}|1-\phi(t)|=1$ which contradicts your last displayed equation a tiny bit.

Comment: Yes, this conclusion holds for a measure concentrated on two points by using a similar argument to the one point case!  I also tried the example of $k$ discrete points (following some distribution, e.g. exponential, etc) by numerical experiments. Based on kimchi lover's example, I think this suggests that this conclusion might be true when $k$ is large but we need to allow the length of interval $[1,5]$ to grow with $k$.

Answer (score 1):

The function $\psi(t)=(1-t^2)\exp(-t^2/2)$ is the characteristic function of a random variable with density function $z^2\exp(-z^2/2)/\sqrt{2\pi}$.  Similarly, $\psi(2t)$ is also
a characteristic function.  But $\psi(t)<0$ for all $t>1$, and so $\min_{t\in[1,5]}|1-\psi(2t)|>1$.

Comment: Thanks!! This is a really great counterexample!